# In Google data studio I have the following Data, How to make a perfect graph?

Tags: looker-studio

The data of my graph for "Name" w.r.t Date, Data 1, Data 2, Data 3, Data 4 as mentioned in table

| Date | Data 1 | Data 2 | Data 3 | Data 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 Nov | 2500 | 150000 | 1.5% | 15 |
| 21 Nov | 2600 | 200000 | 1.6% | 13 |
| 22 Nov | 2300 | 170000 | 1.3% | 17 |
| 23 Nov | 2750 | 180000 | 1.25% | 5 |
| 24 Nov | 2350 | 190000 | 1.15% | 9 |
| 25 Nov | 2250 | 130000 | 1.05% | 7 |
| 26 Nov | 2950 | 120000 | 0.25% | 3 |

But the graph I am getting in Google Data Studio is just giving me straight line for Data 3 and Data 4 because Data 2 is high.

I want the graph to look like [image: Graph 1]

But on Google Data studio I am getting this graph

[image: Graph 2]

blue represents data 1
violet represents Data 2
green represents data 3
orange represents data 4

I tired changing axis but did not find any solution,

Answer (score 0):

not perfect but you could try something alike this maybe.
overlay one graph over another by having a transparent grid.

- first graph Data 1 (left-axis) and Data 2 (right-axis)
- second graph Data 3 (left-axis) and Data 4 (right-axis)

[image]

Comment: This is what I did. But it showed the value of only 1 on hover

Comment: yeah it would only show one graph values on hover. that's the not-perfect part.

Comment: Is there a way to show upside down data with formula?

Comment: sorry I cant think of any such way. hoping someone else would pitch in and offer a way or so...